# In IIS 7: how do I set up a default Error Document for any Error

Tags: iis-7

I'd like to user 'error.html' for any error IIS may encounter.

If i state the following block in my webconfig the site refuses to run.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Replace" defaultPath="/error.html" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/401.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/403.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/500.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Notice the Attribute **defaultPath="/error.html"** in the root element.

I'm getting the following error

HTTP-Fehler 500.19 - Internal Server Error
... 
Konfigurationsfehler: Sperrverletzung  
...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit 
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

Set the Line:

```
<httpErrors lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated,defaultPath">
```

To:

```
<httpErrors lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated">
```

Comment: did not fix it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the IIS 7 Manager to set this properly.
Also, you could maybe do this:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.html">
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This is for the asp.net config, which works under iis 6 too, right?

In IIS 7 is a new Module CustomErrorModule, which works for all errors, not just for Errors generated by asp.net.

In short: your solution configures the error handling of asp.net and mine configures error handling of IIS 7

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Fabian's answer you can also find that file in:

***solution folder* -> .vs (usually this folder is hidden) -> config**